# How to identify which session the websocket connection is from?

Tags: node.js, express, express-session, ws

I'm working on the game. Each player has a session in which after sign in I keep his name. After sign in, each player connects via the websocket. 
How can I tie a player session to a websocket? I would like to make sure that each player session could open only one websocket at the same time, if he opens another one (for example in new tab) I close the previous one.

```
let express = require('express'),   
    app = express(),
    cookie = require('cookie'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    server = require('http').Server(app), 
    webSocket = require('ws'),
    session = require('express-session');

let wss = new webSocket.Server({ 
        verifyClient: (info, done) => {
            sessionParser(info.req, {}, () => {
            // there is no connect.sid when I place application on server, however on local it exists
                done(info.req.session);
            });
    }, server 
});

const sessionParser = session({
    secret: '$eCuRiTy',
});

app.use(sessionParser);

server.listen(3000);

app.post('/signIn', async function(req, res) {
        console.log(req.sessionID); // I want to get the sessionID in websocket
        res.send(true);
});

wss.on('connection', async function(ws, req) {
    console.log(req.sessionID);  // I want to get sessionID from post req.sessionID
});
```

If I run the application on a local host, everything works fine.
req.sessionID from post is the same like req.sessionID in websocket.

However, if I place the application on the server, the sessions are different.
In headers in info object at verifyClient connect.sid doesnt exist.

How can I fix it?